# What happens when a CTE query is interrupted

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have the following query.

```
WITH d_rows AS (DELETE FROM t_a RETURNING * )  INSERT INTO t_b SELECT * FROM d_rows;
```

What will happen if i cancel this query (Ctrl+c in psql)? Will the delete run? Does it run already? Does it run in batches? I see the t_b is growing while the query is running. This is important to know since this is about a *lot* of data.

Comment: Did you try doing that? Cancelling? What was the result?

Comment: everything was rolled back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CTE isn't any different to any other statement in this regard - *it runs within a transaction*. If no transaction is already open then one is opened for the statement and committed *only at the successful completion of the whole statement*.

Thus, if you interrupt the CTE, all effects will roll back and nothing will happen<sup>1</sup>. If you interrupt it just at the moment it is committing then it might commit and *all* take effect, but either *all* or *none* of the CTE will take effect. Individual CTE sub-terms cannot take effect by themselves.

So ... the delete might run, but if so, its effects will not be committed and will be rolled back when the query is cancelled. Exactly how it's executed does not matter. PostgreSQL could choose to batch it, execute it row-by-row, or execute the whole DELETE and feed all its results into the INSERT. It doesn't matter, because the effects will be the same.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Well, strictly a whole lot of table bloat could be created, but there are no effects logically visible to other transactions*.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did cancel. The original table t_a was just 50GB. After 2 days t_b was only 18GB and I canceled the query. t_b remained 18GB, no rollback was performed. So 1 mystery is why this was so damn slow (it's a 10KIOPS EBS storage), and another why it didn't roll back. I may have to merge data manually.

Comment: When a rollback is performed the table won't shrink, the rows are just marked rolled back instead of being marked committed in the transaction log. If you cancelled the query, the rows were not committed and will not be visible to other transactions.

Comment: 18GB is the size shown using \d+, not the size on disk. select * from t_b limit 1 takes forever now, so perhaps the rollback will also take 2 days to complete..

Comment: @sivann No, you are confusing rollback (which is a transactional, logical thing) with the underlying storage. The rows aren't actually added then removed, they're just never marked as committed. The rollback is instant, but it doesn't make the storage for the rows go away. If you want that, you must `VACUUM FULL` or `CLUSTER` the table. Or just `VACUUM` it normally; the database will skip large empty sections of the table. Read the manual on MVCC to understand more: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I thought \d+ estimated an actual data size somehow, not disk size. The query was actually rolled back, the t_b is empty exactly as you described. Thanks.